Logical shift right without dedicated shift instruction
I am working with an assembly language that does not contain either multiply, divide, or bit-shift instructions. I am aware that a left bit-shift can be achieved by just adding the same number to itself - add A, A - but I am unsure about a right bit-shift. How would I go about implementing a right bit-shift with instructions such as add, sub, not, and and or?
There is also adc and sbb if that helps. It's an instruction set for a homebrew computer I was designing, and I wanted to see if it was possible with the instruction set I have implemented.
The full instruction set is add, sub, adc, sbb, nand, or, cmp, mv, ld, st, lda, lpm, push, pop, jnz, and halt.

What a strange omission. Can you link to the complete instruction set? Is this a real problem for a real machine, or a theoretical exercise?

So far it's literally impossible, for all the operations listed the lower bits do not depend on the higher bits, so there is no way to move information "downwards" at all. If you sneak in something like a "branch if zero" then you can at least do it bit-by-bit.

LC-3 by any chance?  It has those same limitations, no divide or multiply, no right shift.  So, just write a loop to copy bits and stop one short of the word size.

@ErikEidt - an add with carry, such as adc, would make the bit copy simpler.

@rcgldr, yes I suppose, though LC-3, for example doesn't have a carry flag.

@ErikEidt - so using and on most significant bit to set a condition then setting least significant bit to 0 or 1, and then add to shift left?

Yeah, that's the idea.  You may not need and on MSB if you have less than zero test.

@NateEldredge: The toy / teaching architecture LC-3 is like this.  It is indeed a strange omission, perhaps to give students a problem to solve in implementing the operation?  According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Computer_3#The_LC-3b there's an LC-3b variant of it which adds a shift opcode which can go either direction.

Sorry, there is also adc and sbb if that helps. It's an instruction set for a homebrew computer I was designing, and I wanted to see if it was possible with the instruction set I have implemented

The full instruction set is add, sub, adc, sbb, nand, or, cmp, mv, ld, st, lda, lpm, push, pop, jnz, and halt

Right shift with just the initial set of arithmetic and logical ops was impossible. adc paired with add makes it trivial, though. Just do add REG, REG to "shift out" highest bit into carry and clear the lowest bit, and then do a series of "adc REG, REG" which would "roll left through carry" that register, with carry going into lowest bit, highest bit going out into carry, and the rest moving left. Do it N-1 time and you've got a logical right shift.

related: Implementing a logical shift right, Binary Right Shift, Given Only Addition

There are several ways to accomplish a right shift on a limited machine — though I think most of them require compare & branch operations, since they involve both looping and conditional operation.

Right shift is like dividing by 2.  So, one way is by division by 2, which your machine doesn't have directly, but can be simulated with repetitive subtraction.  Write a loop to subtract 2 (add -2) and count how many times you can do that; that count will be the original value divided by 2 (leaving the remainder as leftover).

Otherwise, we can copy bits, one at a time, to a new location.

Start with a zero value as the result value, and a copy of the original value if you need it after, otherwise the following will modify the original.

Initialize a loop counter.

Loop:

Test whether the high bit is set in the original if so then add 1 to the result value.  To test the high bit, check if it is negative.

Increment/decrement and test loop counter, if at 15 iterations then exit the loop.  (Assuming 16 bit machine/word size here).

Otherwise, double the original, and double the result value, and repeat.




That will accomplish a logical right shift.  Copy the original sign bit if you want arithmetic right shift.
That copies a bit at a time from the left (most significant), and if you went 16 iterations, you'd have an exact copy of the original, but by stopping short at 15 iterations, you have a 1-bit right shift of the original, and, the original is reduced to the remainder (though now in the msb position).

Alternatively, start with two values having exactly one bit set, each:

The first, call it input position is 0000000000000010₂, and

The second, call it output position is 0000000000000001₂

And a result value initialized to 0.

Then loop 15 times doing the following:

"and" the original value with the input position
if that value is non-zero then "or" the output position into the result value
double the input position (left shift)
double the output position (left shift)




Yet another approach (very inefficient), based on trying possibilities:

start a loop counter, say i, at 0
loop

if i + i equals the original value, then stop, answer is i
if i + i + 1 equals the original value, same
add 1 to i
repeat



